# Unity clamped UI Image is shaking

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using the followng script to clamp the UI Image to the player in 2D game, but when the player is moving, the image is shaking a little. What am I doing wrong?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HealthBarClamp : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform targetToFollow;
    Transform thisTransform;   

    void Start()
    {
        thisTransform = transform;
    }


    void Update()
    {
        thisTransform.position = new Vector3(targetToFollow.position.x, 
            targetToFollow.position.y + 1.5f, thisTransform.position.z); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to do it in `LateUpdate`

Comment: I have never dealed with a problem of this kind, but you can try to make the health bar children of your target in the gameObject hierarchy, so that it moves along with it with no need of updating its position in a script. You can then enable/disable the health bar upon your needs if you need it to be seen or not.

Comment: @derHugo LateUpdate didn`t help me
@RustyBucketBay This actually helped me (with changing render mode to world space, thanx!!!)

Comment: @RustyBucketBay but If I want to add more interface Component with other render mode this solution does not seem valueable

Comment: But that would be a new problem ;) If you can explain what you want and what the problem is in deteail, sure you'll get some juicy help. I posted my comment as an answer, you can check it as accepted if you think it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to make the health bar children of your target in the gameObject hierarchy, so that it moves along with it with no need of updating its position in a script. You can then enable/disable the health bar upon your needs if you need it to be seen or not

Answer (score 0):

If you're moving the target object around using physics or in `FixedUpdate`, then you'll need to move the camera around in `FixedUpdate` as well. `Update` happens every frame, fast or slow, whereas `FixedUpdate` is *simulated* to happen at consistent intervals to help keep physics calculations from going nuts. If you move the camera in `Update` and the target in `FixedUpdate`, then you'll end up with tiny differences that look like shaking.

(Or you can follow the advice given in the comments. It works perfectly fine to make a UI element a child of the moving object, although I personally prefer to do it the way you had it originally because it makes things like "smooth" camera movement easier.)